# Limitar cantidades en base de datos Django

Tags: django, django-models

les escribo porque no encuentro una respuesta a mi problema.
Tengo una pequeña base de datos con el siguiente modelo

```
from django.db import models
class Socio(models.Model):
    nroSoc = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=False)
    dni = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

Y tengo que limitar la cantidad de registros a guardar a 200, como lo puedo manejar?

Muchas gracias

Comment: eso no es asunto del modelo en django amigo, una opción es hacer un select max(id) para ver si ya tienes el registro 200 y en caso afirmativo no permitir ingresos de nuevo o hacer un select count(*) de tu tabla para ver si ya tienes los 200 registros; pero creeme no es algo que declares en el modelo y ya quede solucionado

Comment: Hola Shadow, entonces donde lo declararía? La verdad que estoy muy perdido.

Comment: esto es mas a nivel del terreno de una base de datos, te recomiendo regresar a esa parte ahi te noto perdido, por otro lado no se bien la estructura de django pero yo lo haria en el controlador con un condicional, hago primero la consulta que me indique si ya tengo los 200 registros en casi afirmativo retorno al user al home, en caso contrario procede el alta de un nuevo registro

Comment: Es una posibilidad, la vista es la que se encarga de manejar la lógica (símil controlador en un modelo MVC).
Tendría que ver bien en el view.py como lo puedo manejar.

Comment: La vista es la capa de presentación de los datos considera eso

Comment: Si estás manejando la creación de los `Socios` a través de un formulario, puedes controlar la creación del número máximo en el método `save` del formuario. Yo lo haría así.

Comment: Yo seguiría el consejo del compañero @shadow. Si quisieras mantener los 200 registros más recientes, puedes controlarlos a través del CRON, es decir, permitir que se creen los registros y que el CRON elimine los más antiguos. Como aclaración: en django, 'model' es el objeto, bean.., 'View' es el controlador, donde se realiza la lógica de negocio, y 'template' es la vista donde se renderizan los datos. Ánimo que la solución la tienes cerca!!

Comment: Hola amigo pudiste solucionar tu problema, serias tan amable de explicarme como lo hiciste es que yo igual tengo ese problema quiero que solo guarde 200 registro.